# Not save image in PDF getting error in node/expressJs

Tags: node.js, pdf, express

I have expressJs application i am going to save image in PDF file Here is my code to save image in pdf file

```
exports.getPDF = function (req, res) {
  doc = new PDF();
  doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./public/Competition.pdf'));  
    db.competitions.find({where: {id: req.params.competitionId}}).success(function(competition){

    //MY_URL_IS = http://d16dgegkincj5i.cloudfront.net/1_2_brandLogo_new_update_code-thumbnail.png

    var options = {
        host: 'http://d16dgegkincj5i.cloudfront.net',
        port: 80,
        path: '/1_2_brandLogo_new_update_code-thumbnail.png'
    }

    var request = http.get(options, function(res){
      var imagedata = ''
      res.setEncoding('binary')

      res.on('data', function(chunk){
        imagedata += chunk
      })

      res.on('end', function(){
        fs.writeFile('./public/Competition.pdf', imagedata, 'binary', function(err){
          if (err) throw err
          console.log('File saved.')
        })
      })
    })
  }).error(function(error){
  });
};
```

I am getting error

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

when i get image by http.get and after write to pdf file it will give error and not writing image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

means that the url was not found.

Just removing the `http://` from your host should do the job, like:

```
var options = {
    host: 'd16dgegkincj5i.cloudfront.net',
    port: 80,
    path: '/1_2_brandLogo_new_update_code-thumbnail.png'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But one issue is image save as pdf not in pdf file is there any mistake in my code

Comment: Ok @Sarkar, I understand. I don't know (you didn't said in your question) the module you're using to create your pdf file. But the fact is: now it's another problem, since the the error that you've mentioned was fixed by the solution provided. Feel free to ask another question explaining the current problem now in detail, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: I have a node.js application in which I'm using pdfkit to generate pdf documents. I want to be able to include images from a url in the pdf file